# Passing THIS Object as an jQuery Selector in Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pass-by-reference

I am trying to achieve something like that:

```
function theMain (sel,call) {
    var el = $(sel) ;
    // Some processes etc...
    call("done") ;
}

theMain("div a",function(state){
    if (state == "done") {
        // Want "THIS" to be an DOM object,
        // But it refers WINDOW object...
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red") ;
    }
}) ;
```

**jQuery makes that somehow, but how?**

Or do I have to do it like that:

```
function theMain (sel,call) {
    var el = $(sel) ;
    // Some processes etc...
    call(el,"done") ;
}

theMain("div a",function(that,state){
    if (state == "done") {
        that.css("border","1px solid red") ;
    }
}) ;
```

Any suggest?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want "THIS" to be an DOM object in the first code, but it refers WINDOW object @LeeTaylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `call` to do this.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

```js
function theMain (sel,callback) 
{
    var $sel = $(sel);
    callback.call($sel, "done")
}

theMain("div a",function(state)
{
    if (state == "done") 
    {
      // this now refers to the jquery object (as above in $sel)
        this.css("border","1px solid red") ;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<a href="#" >hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was appreciated!

Comment: @Anonymous What makes you think that? Given that the OP has accepted the answer...?